# Login error with Remote Desktop to Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, rdp

I use [Ubuntu Cloud Guest](http://try.cloud.ubuntu.com) account and install xrdp (`sudo apt-get install xrdp`) then I use [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) of Windows to remote it. But on login step I always get this error after I enter username and password even though I did enter them very carefully.

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to sesman
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did you get it fixed? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No, still don't have solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, there are several problems with xrdp on ubuntu it seems. I found this page useful for solving some of the others, especially the keyboard problem with non-us keyboard.

As regards the login issue, there needs to be a group setup on the ubuntu machine called "tsusers", i added this group via the gui, but i believe there is a command line tool to do the same. You username that you want to login to xrdp will also need to be a member of this group. so user "john" (you) will need to have a group made "tsusers". Also for inexperienced users (such as myself!), when you login, login as "john", not "John", i believe linux usernames are actually all lowercase not first letter capitalised as it is for the gui login to ubuntu.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

> Introduction xrdp is a Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) Server, allowing
>   RDP clients to be presented an X windows desktop to the user.

**Setup**
First install xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get -y install xrdp
```

Next, change the encryption level to high from the default **low**:

```
sudo nano /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
encrypt_level=high
```

Next, allow just RDP through the local firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 3389/tcp
```

***But one thing more***

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

. Change Password Authentication to `yes from no`, then save and exit.

**Note** After making this change, press SHIFT+ : [colon] to open a new command entry box in the vim editor. Type wq, and then press Enter to save changes and exit vim.
     Restart the SSH daemon to make this change take effect.

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Temporarily gain root privileges and change the password for the ubuntu user to a complex password to enhance security. Press the Enter key after typing the command `passwd ubuntu`, and you will be prompted to enter the new password twice.

```
 sudo –i passwd ubuntu
```

Finally, restart xrdp and you should be able to connect:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the configuration has to be adapted.

Either add the user you want to use to the standard `tsusers` group (which you might have to create first), as defined in `/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini`, or uncomment the lines in `sesman.ini` where the group requirements are defined.

Also take care about the keymap/keyset: it has a fallback to the US keymap so special characters are entered in another way.
It might not have been preloaded (or auto-detected) and so has to be generated from the console (`km-xxxx.ini` in `/etc/xrdp`)

A new keymap can be created with `xrdp-genkeymap`, though you might be out of luck  if you have for example a Swiss German keymap; then you might have to copy a working `km-xxxx.ini` file to the `/etc/xrdp` directory, eg: `ch-DE -> km-0807.ini`

You might also want to take a look at the logos if you want to adapt the login experience which are located in `/usr/share/xrdp` or `/usr/local/share/xrdp`

You might also want to look through the xrdp documentation
http://www.xrdp.org (the www. is required ..)
or the github page https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp

Comment: for the installation i have been using the http://askubuntu.com/questions/498873/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty .. scarygliders X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same ".... xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed".
Finally, I found out that the problem (in my case) was that the keyboard set in /etc/xrdp was not the keyboardcode of my Windows desktop...
In /etc/xrdp/" different “km-0xxx.ini”  files are installed by default.
I found that the keycode for my desktop-PC wasn't there.
Here you find all te codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx 
I renamed all the “km-0xxx.ini” in /etc/xrdp to “km-0xxx.ini.BAK” and then downloaded and copied in /etc/xrdp my right keycode (km-0831 in my case of a belgain-french azerty keyboard). Since then: everything OK.
Don't know if you face the same problem...
Success!